# Characterization of Prufer rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The definition for a Prufer ring given by Butts and Smith in "Prufer rings" (1967) is

Definition 1.  $R$ is a Prufer ring if and only if, for each $P$ proper prime ideal of $R$, the ideals of $R_P$ are linearly ordered.

Another definition is

Definition 2. A ring is a Prufer ring if all its regular finite ideals are invertible.

Now what I want is to prove the equivalence between these two definitions. Any link to a book or article where this is done is welcomed, as well as any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two definition are actually not equivalent, although they are in the domain case. Definition 1 is what is usually challed an *arithmetical ring*. Check out this [note](http://www.math.unipd.it/~bazzoni/ricerca/pruefer.pdf). You can see from Theorem 2.15 that the definitions are not equivalent. Also you find some nice characterizations there.